# How to properly wait for next second tick

Tags: java, sleep

I'm working on real-time system. Which requires balancing load per second. So when computing is done I've to put a thread to sleep state till next second right now I'm doing this by:

```
Thread.sleep(((1000 - (Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() % 1000))));
```

but it looks really ugly for me. 
Do you have any tip to improve this?

Comment: `Calendar.getInstance()` will take some time to set up. Instead you could use `System.currentTimeMillis()`

Answer (score 2):

Instead of having the threads all sleep some amount of time, have the threads wait on a signal from a manager thread.

This way, only one thread needs to keep track of ticks, and the others just do work, then wait for a signal to do more work.